# php script repeat itself while running on postgresql

Tags: php, postgresql

I run php script which select/insert to postgresql database.

The problem is that when i run the script to select more than (400000) rows,

the script repeats the insertion for the same rows!

I found this error in postgresql log :

```
2014-12-21 13:14:53 AST LOG:  checkpoints are occurring too frequently (7 seconds apart)
2014-12-21 13:14:53 AST HINT:  Consider increasing the configuration parameter "checkpoint_segments".
```

i changed the configuration to be :

```
- Checkpoints -
checkpoint_segments = 100       # in logfile segments, min 1, 16MB each
checkpoint_timeout = 1h     # range 30s-1h
checkpoint_completion_target = 0.9  # checkpoint target duration, 0.0 - 1.0
checkpoint_warning = 30s        # 0 disables
```

but the problem still occur. can anyone let me know how to fix this?

**UPDATE**

i start my script with a prepare query:

```
<?php
// * Connect to Specified Database
set_time_limit(0);
$dbconn = pg_connect("host=localhost port=5432 dbname=postgis user=postgres password=****");

    if (!$dbconn) { die("Error in connection: " . pg_last_error());}

// connected to Database
 else{

            //We prepare the PostgreSQL next messages query. At this stage it is sent off to the Database server.

                $nextMessageQuery = pg_prepare($dbconn, 'selectNextMessage',  "
                        WITH 
                            history AS (select id ,userid,assigning_date from userid_history 
                            where id=$2 and assigning_date <$4),
                            accounttbl AS(select timestamp,userid,position from account
                            where timestamp >$1 and position is not null
                            and timestamp between $3 and $4)

                        select  p.value1 ,value2.value3,p.value4, m.userid 
                        from (
                            SELECT min(next.timestamp)AS value3,next.userid,next.id  from(
                            select history.id,accounttbl.userid,accounttbl.timestamp,history.assigning_date,accounttbl.position 
                            from history 
                            inner join accounttbl
                            on(
                            accounttbl.userid=history.userid and 
                            accounttbl.timestamp > history.assigning_date and 
                                ( accounttbl.timestamp <(select min(assigning_date) from history h 
                                                    where h.id=history.id and
                                                    h.assigning_date>history.assigning_date) 
                                                or 
                                                    (select min(assigning_date) from history h 
                                                        where h.id=history.id and h.assigning_date>history.assigning_date)  is null
                                )
                            )
                            where timestamp >$1
                            )next GROUP BY next.userid,next.id 
                        ) value2
                        JOIN nmea m on  m.timestamp=value2.value3 and m.userid=value2.userid ,places p 
                        WHERE  m.position is not null and ST_DWithin(m.position,p.position,0.0217130577252428)order by ST_Distance(p.position,m.position)");


                    ?>
```

this is just to show you how complicated my queries are.

then
select #rows, and
insert or update into new table based on many comparing statements

all are in one complicated script.
Do I have to post it all?

Comment: "the script repeats the insertion for the same rows!" Sounds like a bug in your script, PostgreSQL doesn't duplicate records by itself. The hint about configuration is related, but not the root cause. After changing postgresql.conf, did you also reload this new configuration? If not, the old settings are still active.

Comment: Sounds like a bug in your php. Can you post your script?

Comment: X-posted from http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/88819/7788

Comment: Frequent checkpoints just suggest that your performance will be relatively poor for data loading. It's nothing to do with the actual contents of the data that gets loaded. At this point the question looks like "I have a bug in my script or SQL somewhere, can you help me find it"... which is hard without a *complete picture* of the situation - schema, data, and code - and a bunch of time put into it. Perhaps you should start by narrowing down the problem, producing a minimal test case that still demonstrates the issue. You'll probably find and fix the problem in the process.

Comment: Um. The script fragment you posted *doesn't even contain an insert*. So clearly it's not the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all ,

as Craig mentioned there was a bug in the data itself not in the data loading.

actually, there is a replication in certain records that we select!

so i used :

SELECT DISTINCT on (time , id) time , id ,....  FROM table